# how to place text at certain points of image with html and css

Tags: html, css

I have an image that I would like to place next to certain points of, is there any way to do it so that it is at the same place on all screen?

This is what I want

[image]

HTML

```
<img alt="star" src="star.png" />
<p>Text</p>
<p>Text</p>
<p>Text</p>
<p>Text</p>
<p>Text</p>
```

how would I do this?

Comment: Wrap image and texts into a container element with `position:relative`, and then position the text elements `absolute` in regard to that. If the whole thing needs to be response, then working with percentage values usually works quite well.

Answer (score 1):

1. HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="container justify_center">
  <p>Text</p>
</div>
  <div class="container">
  <p class="text side_p">Text</p>
  <img id="image" alt="star" src="https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/star-with-no-background-11549726739dvobjtcde5.png" />
  <p class="text side_p">Text</p>
</div>
<div class="container space_between">
  <p class="text bottom_p_left bottom_p">Text</p>
  <p class="text bottom_p_right bottom_p">Text</p>
</div>
</div>
```

2. CSS:

```
#wrapper {
  width: 350px;
}

#image {
  width: 300px
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex
}

.justify_center {
  justify-content: center
}

.space_between {
  justify-content: space-between
}

.text {
  position: relative;
}

.side_p  {
  top: 95px
}

.bottom_p {
  bottom: 25px
}

.bottom_p_left {
  left: 50px
}

.bottom_p_right {
  right: 50px
}
```

3. CodePen:
   https://codepen.io/takhirkudusov/pen/jOXGwez

Comment: You can create a runnable snippet directly in StackOverflow with the `<>` button.